# wso2 Identity Server 5.7.0 Service Provider how set User role?

Tags: wso2, user-roles, service-provider, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 Identity Server have service provider.
I have multiple service provider and multiple user role.
I want:

Role1  access and use Service Provider1.

Role2  access and use Service Provider2.

Role3  access and use Service Provider3.

How can config service provider for role management and role access management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you want a specific user role to access the specific SP. In that case, you can use adaptive authentication[1]. In each Service provider, you have to write an adaptive script to check whether the user has specific roles or not. There is a sample template for role-based authentication scenario[2]

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Adaptive+Authentication
[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Role-Based+Adaptive+Authentication

Comment: I don't want  whether the user has specific roles or not. I just want Role1 to be able to use the serviceProvider1, but Role2 can not use the same service

Comment: In WSO2IS permissions are assigned to roles. Then roles should be assigned to users. Then the user will get the permission relevant to the assigned roles. In your scenario users log into the application/service and you need to allow that user to login, if the particular role is assigned to that user. Isn't it?

Comment: Can you help for write this script?      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67295753/wso2-identity-server-5-7-0-how-write-script-for-role1