# Wso2 Identity Server 5.7.0 Role Management

Tags: wso2, roles, user-roles, service-provider, wso2-identity-server

I Have a Service Provider with openId/Auth2 like this picture:

I just want Role1 to be able to use the serviceProvider1, but Role2 can not use the same service.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177229/wso2-identity-server-5-7-0-service-provider-how-set-user-role

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wso2 Identity Server 5.7.0 Service Provider how set User role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177229/wso2-identity-server-5-7-0-service-provider-how-set-user-role)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure role-based adaptive authentication for Service Provider1 https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-role-based-adaptive-authentication/ and allow only the users who have Role1 to access Service Provider1.